# javascript strange behaviour,why last alert is giving result as false?

Tags: javascript

```js
var value1 = "20";
var value2 = 20;

if (value1 == value2) {
  alert(" equal values");
} else {
  alert("different values");
}

alert("value is " + value1 == value2);
console.log(value1 == value2);
```

Comment: Because `"value is "+value1` is not equal to `value2`. You're seeing the result of `("value is "+value1)==(value2)`. The text `"value is "` doesn't appear, after all.

Answer (score 3):

You need prarentheses to change the [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) to get the comparison into a string, instead of adding a value to a string and get the result of the comparing.

```js
var value1 = "20";
var value2 = 20;

console.log("value is " + value1 == value2);
console.log("value is " + (value1 == value2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

var value1="20";
var value2=20;

```
if(value1==value2){
    alert(" equal values");
}
else{
    alert("different values");
}
```

alert("value is "+(value1==value2));
console.log(value1==value2);